# Missing Plone 4.3 resource: bbb-kss.css

Tags: plone, zope

This isn't an error, per se, but I saw it on a shiny new install of Plone 4.3 and couldn't find anything on Google about it. Is this normal? Is the link incorrect? Will this affect anything? Thanks. :)

This shows up in the **portal_css** registry, in the ZMI.

```
bbb-kss.css — resource not found or not accessible
```

[image: bbb-kss.css — resource not found or not accessible]

Comment: `bbb` would stand for backwards compatibility. Have you tried [filing a bug report](https://dev.plone.org/newticket) yet?

Comment: Ticket filed, thanks for the link Martijn!

Answer (score 1):

No. It likely just means that you removed a product, and it didn't cleanly remove the entries from  portal_css. You can safely just delete that entry (check in portal_javascripts, and portal_kss, too).